# python pandas resample monthly aggregated data to daily, then aggregate back to weekly

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series

Here is my example data:

| team | sales | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 100 | 1/1/2023 |
| a | 200 | 2/1/2023 |
| b | 600 | 1/1/2023 |
| b | 300 | 2/1/2023 |

load in pandas like so:

```
mydata = pd.DataFrame([
['team','sales','month'],
['a',   100,    '1/1/2023'],
['a',   200,    '2/1/2023'],
['b',   600,    '1/1/2023'],
['b',   300,    '2/1/2023']
])
mydata.columns = mydata.iloc[0]
mydata = mydata[1:]  
mydata['month'] = pd.to_datetime(mydata['month'])
```

My desired outcome for team "a" is this data aggregated by each week as starting on Monday, like this:

| team | sales | Monday Week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 22.58 | 1/2/2023 |
| a | 22.58 | 1/9/2023 |
| a | 22.58 | 1/16/2023 |
| a | 22.58 | 1/23/2023 |
| a | 42.17 | 1/30/2023 |
| a | 50 | 2/6/2023 |
| a | 50 | 2/13/2023 |
| a | 50 | 2/20/2023 |
| a | 14.29 | 2/27/2023 |

So the logic on the calculated sales per week is:
$100 of sales in January, so avg sales per day is 100/31 = 3.23 per day, * 7 days in a weeks = $22.58 for each week in January.
February is $200 over 28 days, so ($200/28)*7 = $50 a week in Feb.

The calculation on the week starting 1/30/2023 is a little more complicated. I need to carry the January rate the first 2 days of 1/30 and 1/31, then start summing the Feb rate for the following 5 days in Feb (until 2/5/2023). So it would be 5*(200/28)+2*(100/31) = 42.17

Is there a way to do this in Pandas? I believe the logic that may work is taking each monthly total, decomposing that into daily data with an average rate, then using pandas to aggregate back up to weekly data starting on Monday for each month, but I'm lost trying to chain together the date functions.

Comment: How can team A has sales of 42.17 for week of 1/30/2023? It has zero sales in Feb 2023. Shouldn't its sales be `3.23 * 2 = 6.46`?

Comment: yes, it's 6.46 for the first 2 days, but the rest of the week falls in Feb, therefore you add Feb rate to the next 5 days, since there is no march data feb 27 is just 14.29

Comment: But isn't Feb rate only for team B?

Comment: oh yeah you're right, i guess i made the example ambiguous as the sample is too small. each team has a few hundred records spanning multiple years/months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have miscalculation for team A for the week of `1/30/2023`. It has no sales in Feb so its sales for the week should be `3.23 * 2 = 4.46`.

Here's one way to do that:

```py
def get_weekly_sales(group: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    tmp = (
        # Put month to the index and convert it to monthly period
        group.set_index("month")[["sales"]]
        .to_period("M")
        # Calculate the average daily sales
        .assign(sales=lambda x: x["sales"] / x.index.days_in_month)
        # Up-sample the dataframe to daily
        .resample("1D")
        .ffill()
        # Sum by week
        .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="W"))
        .sum()
    )
    # Clean up the index
    tmp.index = tmp.index.to_timestamp().rename("week_starting")

    return tmp

df.groupby("team").apply(get_weekly_sales)
```

Comment: edited to make less ambiguous, many teams spanning many months. Team A for the week of 1/30 is calculated correctly, it SHOULD include sales in Feb. So the week needs to pick up the rate of Jan for 1/30 and 1/31, then switch to Feb rate for 2/1-2/5

Comment: would this solution fail if month + sales had duplicates? group.set_index("month")[["sales"]] will throw reset index error correct?